# Change the symbol on a specific element in a layer in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, rendering

I want to change the symbol on a one specific feature in the layer after clicking with the mouse. Not using attributes.

In Method canvasPressEvent(self, event) call method oznacPrvok(self, feature):

```
 def oznacPrvok(self, prvok, feature):

    get_styles = QgsStyle.defaultStyle()
    style = get_styles.symbol('topo pop capital')

    # Apply style and repaint symbolism
    # For one feature : self.najdeny_prvok
    feature.setEmbeddedSymbol(style)

    # For all features on layer: self.activeLayer
    # self.activeLayer.renderer().setSymbol(style)
    self.activeLayer.triggerRepaint()
    # iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

It works for all features but nowork for one specific feature.